# Spring boot rest service going down with error : root of context hierarchy

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have my web service backend in Spring boot, After I deploy this service on server I am facing issues as service goes down after some time. I am making jar and running jar on server.

Below is the log output:

```
2019-02-06 08:15:44.646  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3ab39c39: startup date [Tue Feb 05 20:37:03 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-02-06 08:15:44.649  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2019-02-06 08:15:44.649  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2019-02-06 08:15:44.650  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2019-02-06 08:15:44.652  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2019-02-06 08:15:44.652  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2019-02-06 08:15:44.653  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2019-02-06 08:15:44.653  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
2019-02-06 08:15:44.663  INFO 1165 --- [       Thread-3] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:132213}] to <<server:IP>> because the pool has been closed.
```

Comment: Looks like you using mongodb as your database. To keep your connection alive use this : MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder().socketKeepAlive(true).build(); 
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("host", options);

Comment: Can you show some more lines of the log from before that point?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch before this line my normal logs are available of data received and processed.

Comment: do you have DEBUG level enabled as well for the logging?